# Dynamically Changing Field Names in Pentaho

Tags: etl, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Here is my situation:

1. I have input files
2. I need to output another file
3. None of this is going into a table, I'm just outputting a file.
4. In the input file, the field names can change names, add more fields or remove fields.

Is there a way to change field names dynamically? I have all of the field names into a column, I just need the field names to change based on whatever is in that column at the time without having to manually do it each time this is run.

Comment: Choose a bad caption for your question and watch it sit unanswered for eons.  For example: You ask about changing field names, but I feel you wonder how to process a CSV file without knowing the layout at design time. I could be wrong, though.